# Student-Marks entry query format

Tags: c#, sql, firebird

I am using Firebird. I have 4 tables:

```
**tbl_student**
s_id    s_name     s_gender   c_id
-----------------------------------
1       Mike       M           1
2       Adri       M           4
3       Grij       F           2         

**tbl_class**
c_id     c_name
----------------
1        I
2        II
3        III
4        IV

**tbl_subject**
sub_id    sub_name   sub_max_marks    c_id
-------------------------------------------
1         Maths      100              1
2         Physics    100              1
3         English    50               2     

**tbl_marks**
s_id   sub_id    obtn_marks
-----------------------------------------
1      1         67
2      2         87
3      2         45
```

Now I have created a form (Windows form using c#.net) where the user will have the option to select Class, Subject & Student. Based on these parameters, I want to populate a grid/listview which should look like:

```
Class Name   Student Id     Student Name   Subject Name   Marks Obtained
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
I            1              Mike           Maths
```

Now on clicking the above row of a gridview/listview, an other form would
come up where the user will enter marks obtained by the student in that particular subject.

My problem is that I am unable to populate the gridview/listview in above mentioned format. Any code would be very helpful. So far I have tried the following SQL query:

```sql
SELECT cls.c_name,
stu.s_id, stu.s_name,
sub.sub_name,
mrk.obtn_marks
FROM tbl_student stu
LEFT JOIN tbl_class cls ON cls.c_id = stu.c_id
LEFT JOIN tbl_subject sub ON sub.c_id = cls.c_id
LEFT JOIN tbl_marks mrk ON mrk.s_id = stu.s_id
WHERE cls.cls_id=@cls_id
AND sub.sub_id=@sub_id
AND stu.s_id=@s_id
```

Comment: a good start would be fixing the aliases in your query

Comment: Try to show the code that deals with GridView/ListView.

Comment: It would be very helpful if you tell us what is wrong with the query you tried. My guess would be that you need to join `tbl_marks` on the student id **and** the subject id.